# Android ProgressDialog when creating Database using AsyncTask

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, progressdialog

What to display a `ProgressDialog` when my `database` is created. This is only showed once.

I have this code in my activity:

```
    baseDados.open();
    ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Cursor query = baseDados.getData(1,0,null);
    MyAdapt cursorAdapter = new MyAdapt(this, query,0);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

On the first run, database is created and populated and the result of the query is shown on a `listview`. The code above is used can be used again but this time, the database is not created because it is already created.

On the internet, I saw that the best way to achieve is to use `AsyncTaks` but I'm having trouble in showing the progressdialog and errors on creating the database if I use `AsyncTaks`.

I've created a class to handle my database and there created my `AsyncTaks`.

Here is what I've done:

```
public class Database {

    private DbHelper DBHelper;
    private final Context Context;
    private SQLiteDatabase BaseDados;
    static Context ctx;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, BD_NAME, null, BD_VERSION);
            ctx = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            new loadDB().execute(db);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVesion) {
            // Drop table if table exists
            (....)
            // creates new tables and data
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public class loadDB extends AsyncTask<SQLiteDatabase, Void, Integer> {
            ProgressDialog progresso;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                progresso = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "INFO", "Instaling for the first time") );

            }
            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(SQLiteDatabase... params) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = params[0];
            // Code to create the tables and populate them
            // Lots of code like below
                db.execSQL("SQL statement goes here");      
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Dismiss the ProgressDialog
                progresso.dismiss();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }

    }

    public Database(Context c) {
        Context = c;
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException {
        DBHelper = new DbHelper(Context);
        BaseDados = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData(int tipo, long groupId, String query[]) {
    // querys performed on the database
}
    }
```

I have two problems.

**Problem 1**

ProgressDialog is never shown although it takes almost five seconds to create and populate my database

**Problem 2**

At some point, the app crashes and the database is not correctly created because the querys give error `no such table`
The code for creating an populating the database is OK because if in the method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    new loadDB().execute(db);
}
```

I remove `new loadDB().execute(db);` and put this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL code that was on `doInBackground(SQLiteDatabase... params)`
}
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an AsyncTask to initialize a db inside constructor, especially because immediately after you call constructor you are calling

```
  BaseDados = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

The AsyncTask would not have been run, so your db would not have been created, but you are trying to get a writable database. A better design is to make everything related to databases synchronous, and then use all db related methods in one Asynctask.

Also i think it is bad to mix UI and db operations like you have done. You will have to redesign the whole thing

Comment: basically, Database.open is a synchronous operation that must return only once the DB exists.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you don't need to display a progressdialog at all:

1. if your db creation is short enough (most of the cases), you can do it synchronously.
2. if not, you can embed a pre-existing database and copy it. it is faster, and putting a progressdialog on a file copy is quite simple. See this example for how to embed your database in your apk :

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/